# Use django rest framework with dynamoDB

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a database DynamoDB and I would like to see the information using django-rest-framework.
The database is created and populated using another application ... !!!

Comment: Please clearify what your question is!

Comment: I would like to know how to make an api-rest with django-rest-framework to bring data from a database in DynamoDB

Comment: https://wmerobertson.wordpress.com/2016/02/02/dynamodb-django-part-2-implementing-dynamodb-in-django/

Answer (score 0):

To use DynamoDB in your Python project you need install Amazon SDK. Here is the documentation:

http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/python/

Here is easy to understand tutorial how to make queries and import SDK into your project.

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamodb_tut.html

Then you just need to parse response and create API what your need.

I am assuming that it is DynamoDB question and you know to parse JSON using Python-Django stack and you know what REST is ;)

Comment: the problem is that django-rest-framework can not handle DynamoDB. As I can make the models and viewset?

Comment: Generally most MVC frameworks use concept of `adapter pattern` between model and database engine.

I didn't try `django-rest-framework`. But I used `DynamoDB` for `Sails` - it is REST framework, based on `NodeJS`. And the solution was to use `sails-dynamodb` adapter(from official `npm` package repository).

You can try to find similar `DynamoDB` adapter to your framework(Unfortunately I didn't find it).

Or, if you don't find, you need write it by yourself :)